# Python: MemoryError for .corr(method='pearson').applymap

Tags: python, vectorization, data-analysis, pearson-correlation

I am trying to calculate the pearsons correlation for every single possible pair of two columns in a dataframe. I have 57997 columns. But I am getting a memory error.

```
t_logs = logs.T
print t_logs
results = t_logs.corr(method='pearson').applymap
print results[enter image description here][1]
```

Here is the trace back

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-d0010a131d17> in <module>()
       5 print logs
       6 
 ----> 7 results = t_logs.corr(method='pearson')
       8 print results

C:\Users\nne1s\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in 
corr(self, method, min_periods)
   4938 
   4939         if method == 'pearson':
-> 4940             correl = libalgos.nancorr(_ensure_float64(mat), 
minp=min_periods)
4941         elif method == 'spearman':
4942             correl = libalgos.nancorr_spearman(_ensure_float64(mat),

pandas\_libs\algos.pyx in pandas._libs.algos.nancorr 
(pandas\_libs\algos.c:15501)()

MemoryError:
```

[picture of code linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUZaD.png)

Comment: How much ram do you have on your development environment

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or error messages. Post the full traceback here on SO instead. [The reason for this is explained here.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: @Piinthesky I added the trace back

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to calculate correlation coefficients for 57997 series.

If you're trying to get the correlation matrix for Log2 of Mean, Log2 of STD, etc. transpose the dataframe before you run corr

```
t_logs = t_logs.T
results = t_logs.corr(method='pearson')
```

I'm not sure what you wanted to do with `applymap` here

Comment: can you post the entire traceback?

Comment: When I do it without transposing it I do not get the error. However, I need to to be transposed to take the correct correlation coefficient

Comment: what's the shape of the resulting dataframe when you use corr without transposing?

Comment: it is a 4x4. but essentially i need a 57997x57997. Maybe it is just too large

Comment: to help me find the relationship between 2 genes and their expression.